# Activating error messages in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `laravel 4.2`. It is basically a fresh installation. However, when receiving an error I get a page with:

`Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

How to activate detailed error messages during development?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the way you should do. You should use environments for that.

Go to `bootstrap\start.php`.

In:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(     
    'local' => array('yourpcname'),    
));
```

Put your PC name here.

Now in `app/config/app.php` make sure you have:

```
'debug' => false,
```

because you don't want to display errors when on production and you could forget about changing it when moving on production.

Now in `app/config/local/app.php` make sure you have:

```
'debug' => true,
```

Now in local environment you will have displayed errors in details and when moving to production standard messages as you have no (of course unless you won't create custom error page for that).

Comment: It is the "way you should do."  According to the question that's the right answer.  I also included a reference to your answer.  He asked how to get the debug screens instead of the generic errors, not how to set up his app. for different environments.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff OP asked how to turn on error messages during development. You told him how to turn off messages on production and use production as development, so after copying files to webhost he would have error messages visible also on production.

Comment: Never told him how to turn off anything not sure what you're talking about.  Read my answer maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `project/app/config/app.php` and set `debug` = `true`

To have it be set to `true` in dev. and `false` on production look into setting up environment variables.