# Laravel 4.2 Stack Trace not appearing while running on an apache server

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started to learn Laravel and i'm running in to an issue with stack traces not appearing while i'm running on my local apache environment.

I've configured the bootstrap/start.php file along with the app\config\local\app.php file and i'm not seeing the stack trace if, for example, i tried to jump to a page that hadn't been created yet.

All i see is a 404 Not found page.

When i run the php artisan serve command and view the project there, the stack traces appear fine.

Am i missing a config setting in my apache set up?

EDIT: It had to do with my apache setup. This link helped:
[laravel 4 all routes except home result in 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activating error messages in laravel 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318052/activating-error-messages-in-laravel-4-2)

Comment: i've looked at that thread and a few others, have my files set up as they do but it's just not working when running on my apache server. it works fine when i run the php artisan serve command.

Comment: Change debug to true in both environments and try to display some unexisting variable

Comment: i set up a route, which i can't access while running on my local apache server so it seems to be more than just the stack traces not appearing.

The same route is working fine when running the artisan serve command